# Specify include directories for resources in command line

Tags: windows, curl, libcurl, nmake, rc

I am trying to build cURL on Windows using the following line:

```
nmake vc-x64 mode=dll VC=10 MACHINE=x64
```

Now I have done this setup before building:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64;%PATH%
set INCLUDE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include"
set LIB="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\amd64"
set LIBPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64"
set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\x64";%PATH%)
set INCLUDE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include";%INCLUDE%
set LIB="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64";%LIB%
```

I get the following error:

```
        rc /dDEBUGBUILD=0 /Fo ..\builds\libcurl-vc10-x64-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-w
inssl-obj-lib\libcurl.res ..\lib\libcurl.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.7600.16385
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

..\lib\libcurl.rc(22) : fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winver.h'.

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A
\Bin\x64\rc.EXE"' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\bin\amd64\nmake.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\bin\amd64\nmake.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

It does not seem to find the file "winver.h" despite the fact that this file is in the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include", and that this directory is in my `INCLUDE` variable.
It looks like `rc` does not take in account the variable INCLUDE to find the include paths. Is there a way to add an include path for the `rc` command? Unless this is something completely different of course.